# Understanding the Euler function

Tags: group-theory

It should be very basic and simple question related to the Euler function $\phi$. If I would like to calculate for example $\phi(100)$ I saw that we can write it as $\phi(2^2\cdot 5^2)$. Also I saw a theorem that says $\phi(a\cdot b) = \phi(a)\cdot \phi(b)$ if $a,b$ are prime numbers. So we get $\phi(100)=\phi(2)\phi(2)\phi(5)\phi(5)=1\cdot 1\cdot 4\cdot 4=16$, But it isn't true because I know that $\phi(100)=40$. What is the right why to dismantle $100$ so we can use the euler function?

Comment: $\phi(a\cdot b) = \phi(a)\cdot \phi(b)$ is true when $a,b$ are *coprime*.

Comment: $\phi(a\cdot b) = \phi(a)\cdot \phi(b)$ if $a,b$ are relatively prime, so $\phi(100)=\phi(4)\phi(25)$

Answer (score 1):

$\phi(100) = \phi(5^2 . 2^2) = \phi(2^2) \phi(5^2) = 2 \times (25-20) = 40$

Recall that:

> - $\phi(ab) = \phi(a)\phi(b) \iff a$ and $b$ are coprime i.e $\gcd(a,b) = 1$.
> - $\phi(p^a) = p^{a-1}(p-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

We write $100$ as $2^2\times5^2$. Then, since $\gcd(2^2,5^2)=1$,$$\phi(2^2\times5^2)=\phi(2^2)\times\phi(5^2).$$And, for any prime $p$, $\phi(p^n)=p^n-p^{n-1}=\left(1-\frac1p\right)p^n$. So, $\phi(2^2)=2$ and $\phi(5^2)=20$. Therefore, $\phi(100)=2\times20=40$.